# USB-C to Ethernet adapter on Mac with jumbo frames

Tags: mac, thunderbolt, ethernet

I have to work with a scientific camera and acquire images via Ethernet on a MacBook Pro 2019 with 4 Thunderbolt 3 ports.

I have a USB-C to Ethernet adapter, and I have to enable jumbo frames (9000 byte MTU), but it seems not possible with USB-C in contrary to Thunderbolt 3.

I cannot find any adapter to convert Thunderbolt 3 to Ethernet though.

Any solution?

Comment: I'd expect the [QNA-T310G1T](https://www.qnap.com/en-us/product/qna-tb-10gbe) to work...the hardware specs don't mention jumbo frames - but in the linked video (at 23:48) it's obvious that they are supported.

Comment: Thanks for this reference. I was just wondering why the same adapter enabling jumbo frames on a Windows pc cannot do the same on a MacBook Pro.

Comment: You mean the *USB-C to Ethernet adapter* you already own? Missing feature in the driver, I guess

Comment: Yes exactly, I tested the adapter I already own and it works perfectly, with jumbo frames, on a Windows pc, while on the MacBook the MTU is limited to 1500 byte.

Comment: May I ask which adapter do you have? I'm on the same situation.